# How to change the position of status message for an embedded node?

Tags: 9

I have an embedded node that uses JavaScript.

I have added a message.

```
const messages = new Drupal.Message();
messages.add(
  Drupal.t('Please select option'),
  { type: 'error' }
);
```

The message is shown at the top of the page. How can i move the message to the top of the embedded node instead?

(embedded node is at the bottom of the original node)

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to use status message block.
I found out that i could change the position of message like this:

```
const messages =  new Drupal.Message(document.querySelector('#data-gallup-messages'))
messages.add(
    Drupal.t('Please select option'),
    { type: 'error' }
  );
}
```

and of-course the div i assign the message to needs to exist in twig.

```
<div id='data-gallup-messages'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal status messages are shown in the **Status messages** block.  You can configure where that block is placed at `/admin/structure/block`.

The exact placement of the block depends on your theme's available regions.